# multi threads modify a global list in python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

i want to add an item into a global list every 2 seconds in one thread,
and save the list into database before empty it  every 3 seconds in another thread.

i create two local varibles to monitor the total added items and total saveditems, they should be equal every 6 senconds,but it is not.
here is my code:

```
import datetime
import psutil,os,time
from threading import *
class AddToList(Thread):
    totalAdded=0
    def run(self):
        lock=RLock()
        lock.acquire()
        while True:
            entryList.append("AddToList at "+str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            self.totalAdded=self.totalAdded+len(entryList)
            print("totalAdded:"+str(self.totalAdded))
            time.sleep(2)
        lock.release()
class SaveList(Thread):
    totalSaved=0
    '''save entry to server'''
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        lock=RLock()
        lock.acquire()
        while True:
            #save list to database,then empty the list
            self.totalSaved=self.totalSaved+len(entryList)
            del entryList[:]
            print("totalSaved:"+str(self.totalSaved))
            time.sleep(3)
        lock.release()

if __name__=="__main__":
    global entryList
    entryList=[]
    addClass= AddToList()
    addClass.start()
    saveClass=SaveList()
    saveClass.start()
```

result:

```
totalAdded:2
totalSaved:2
totalAdded:3
totalSaved:3totalAdded:4

totalAdded:6
totalSaved:5
totalAdded:7
totalSaved:6
totalAdded:8
totalAdded:10
totalSaved:8
totalAdded:11
totalSaved:9
totalAdded:12
totalAdded:14
totalSaved:11
totalAdded:15
totalSaved:12
...........
...........
totalAdded:51
totalSaved:39totalAdded:52

totalAdded:54
totalSaved:41
totalAdded:55
totalSaved:42
totalAdded:56
totalAdded:58
totalSaved:44
totalAdded:59
totalSaved:45totalAdded:60
......
......
```

i anm new to python and searched a lot about threading ,Lock and RLock ,but with no luck.
where am wrong?

Comment: Great question. Also as a tip to a new python dev, you should avoid using globals at all cost. Also be aware that you're using [class variables instead of instance variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657867/class-variable-vs-instance-variable-python) which I don't think you meant to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make `Lock` and `RLock` work you must use the *same* object in every thread. The lock objects must have the same "visibility" of the object that you want to "protect".

Here is a new version of you code which should work. It also avoid using things like global variables etc.

```
import datetime
import time
import threading

class AddToList(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, lock, entryList):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.totalAdded = 0
        self.entryList = entryList
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.lock.acquire()
            entryList.append("AddToList at {}".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
            self.totalAdded += 1
            self.lock.release()
            print("totalAdded: {}".format(self.totalAdded))
            time.sleep(2)


class SaveList(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, lock, entryList):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.totalSaved = 0
        self.entryList = entryList
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.totalSaved += len(self.entryList)
            del self.entryList[:]
            self.lock.release()
            print("totalSaved: {}".format(self.totalSaved))
            time.sleep(3)


if __name__=="__main__":
    lock=threading.Lock()
    entryList=[]

    addClass = AddToList(lock, entryList)
    addClass.start()

    saveClass = SaveList(lock, entryList)
    saveClass.start()
```

Some things to note:

1. Use Lock instead of RLock when you don't have any particular needs. RLock is much slower.
2. As already pointed out by *someone* it is better avoid using global variables when not needed. Also Class variables should be used only when it makes sense.
3. When you use a lock you should try to limit as much as possible the code between acquire and release. In you previous code you never release the lock.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. i have defined a global lock object  and replace the local lock object in each threading, but the result is as same as above.

Comment: Maybe you are assuming that the threads will be executed in a particular order or that those `sleep` will last exactly for the number of seconds that you passed to them. This is not true.

Comment: yes, i don't expect they are equal in every accurate 6 seconds, but they should be equal in some time, and the gap between them won't be get bigger and bigger.

Comment: thanks for your work, but the result is  same , the gap get bigger and bigger when running         totalAdded: 12
totalAdded: 14
totalSaved: 11
totalAdded: 15
totalSaved: 12
totalAdded: 16
totalAdded: 18
totalSaved: 14
totalAdded: 19
totalSaved: 15
totalAdded: 20
totalAdded: 22
totalSaved: 17:

Comment: `self.totalAdded += len(entryList)` is wrong.  You just added only one item, not `len(entryList)` ones.

Comment: @ArminRigo yes, that's the problem. tks all of you.