# Override the ListView attributes

Tags: python, django

When override the attributes of class view, it comes with:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
```

I assume it should be:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        template_name = 'polls/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
```

How Django achieve it by assign variable directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't take a look at the source code of [Django GenericView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/),
variables that you point out are variables that we can call `class Variables`, these are variables of the class [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). Basically, they are class variables **shared by all instances**.
Whereas inside `__init__` they're called `instance variable`  **Unique to each instance**

A small example (*Not good enough*):

```
class MyView:
    template_name = 'default_name.html' # class variable shared by all instances

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name  # instance variable unique to each instance

    def get_template_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

The first case you show is an example of setting *class* variables.  In the second case, you are actually defining local variables, but I assume you meant to assign *instance* variables like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    self.context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
```

Check out 
and the answers to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657867/class-variable-vs-instance-variable-python) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python) for some discussion of the difference.